# Can signals/events from handsfree accessory of Android phone be intercepted?

Tags: android

I have a strange doubt:
Is it possible to intercept key presses of the hands free mic/headset(whatever it is called) of an Android mobile device?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` broadcast `Intent`. I do not know if that will be broadcast as a result of any user action with a Bluetooth headset. Otherwise, I suspect there is nothing available for you to hook into, sorry.